# Cannot connect to AWS SDK in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to have my EC2 instance assume a role that has AdministratorAccess but I keep getting the following:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::000111222333:assumed-role/Administrator_EC2/i-07e8e4a9cc81cd5fe is not
authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::000111222333:instance-profile/Administrator_EC2
```

My role has the standard EC2 gets sts::assume-role trust policy which I figured should allow me to assume the role but for some reason it's not letting me. I've also associated the role with the EC2 instance in the console. What's going on? Please let me know if I should provide more info

Comment: That error message makes it look like you already are that role (EC2 is allowed to assume it, but the role isn't allowed to assume itself, thus the error)

Comment: So do I need to associate a different role with EC2 and grant assume role to that role?

Comment: It means that you don't need to do anything -- running the AWS CLI or using an AWS SDK on that instance will automatically use the `Administrator_EC2` role because it has already been associated with that instance.